# How to stop filter:blur() from overflowing

Tags: css, blur, css-filters

I'm trying to set a centered image on top of the same image but blurred and stretched to fill horizontally.  When I apply filter:blur() the background image "overflows" as it goes over the height that the original image has.

[image: The blue part should be white]

```
<div class="blurred">

</div>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg">

img{
  height:300px;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}


.blurred{
  background-image:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg');
  filter:blur(30px);
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gw9krd2n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do it like this:

```css
    img {
      position: relative;
      top:-5%; left:-5%; z-index: -1;
      width:110%; height:110%;
      filter: blur(20px);
    }

    .blurred {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: transparent url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg') no-repeat 50% / auto 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="blurred">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/65sf24nz/1/)

Comment: run the snippet full page

Comment: @DianaG, happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to reduce the `30px` of the filter from top add bottom. I added some margin-top for better viewing.

```css
img{
  height:300px;
  margin:20px auto;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}


.blurred{
  background-image:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg');
  filter:blur(30px);
  margin:50px auto;
  width:100%;
  height: calc(300px - 60px);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurred">

</div>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg">
```

You can also optimize the code by using pseudo element and you will have better control.

```css
img {
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.blurred {
  position: relative;
  margin:30px 0;
  z-index:0;
}

.blurred:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg');
  filter: blur(30px);
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurred">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg">
</div>
```

You can also introduce CSS variable for more flexibility:

```css
img {
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.blurred {
  position: relative;
  margin:30px 0;
  z-index:0;
}

.blurred:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg');
  filter: blur(var(--f,20px));
  top: var(--f,20px);
  bottom: var(--f,20px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurred" style="--f:30px">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="blurred" style="--f:50px">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg">
</div>
```

---

Using the pseudo element method, you have also the option to simply hide the overflow:

```css
img {
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.blurred {
  position: relative;
  margin:30px 0;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.blurred:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg');
  filter: blur(20px);
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurred" >
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/1280px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg">
</div>
```